# Sharepoint 2013 list view threshold issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, office365api

I am new to SharePoint 2013, and really appreciate help:

I have three list: List1, List2, List3

and three users: UserA, UserB, UserC

I have web Application where I am making REST API calls to read data from list. When UserA and UserB use application they are able to read data from all the list, they are not facing any issue.

But when UserC is trying to access data from List3 he is getting following error.

`"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."`

I am aware of SharePoint list view Lookup Threshold issue, but there are no lookup columns in list3, UserC is able to read data from other both lists (List1 and List2). All three users have same permission levels.

I need help/hints to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can all three users access the list via the User interface or are you getting the same response?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Comment: through user interface, all three users are able to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my own issue. May be this will help someone else.

When I visited Central Admin, to change List View Threshold value, I increased 'List View Lookup Threshold' value not 'List View Threshold' value.

Though my list was not having lookup columns, my list had more than 5000 items. The moment I increased 'List View Threshold' value my application was working fine. All threee users were able to access data from all lists.

But it was still weird why only one user was facing that issue.